# Jquery FullCalendar- Change event color according to even_type in ruby app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I'm using Jquery full calendar from http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar in my ruby apps. I wanna show different color for 4 different kind of events like (Holidays, School, Work, Fun) which were saved in my events table as type_of_event

Right now I'm fetching events only with start_at and end_at using below code:

```
scope :before, lambda {|end_time| {:conditions => ["ends_at < ?", Event.format_date(end_time)] }}
  scope :after, lambda {|start_time| {:conditions => ["starts_at > ?", Event.format_date(start_time)] }}


  # need to override the json view to return what full_calendar is expecting.
  # http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/
  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      :id => self.id,
      :title => self.title,
      :description => self.description || "",
      :start => starts_at.rfc822,
      :end => ends_at.rfc822,
      :allDay => self.all_day,
      :recurring => false,
      :url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.event_path(id),
      #:color => "red"
    }

  end

  def self.format_date(date_time)
    Time.at(date_time.to_i).to_formatted_s(:db)
  end
```

Is there any specific way to show events color according to their event_type means if event type is school it will show me red color

Answer (score 2):

Are you going to use these colors somewhere else outside of your model?

Most likely, you need not to make it globally available, so just add a constant to the model:

```
scope :before, ...
scope :after, ...

EVENT_COLORS = { "School" => "#ff0000", "Holidays" => "#00ff00", ... }
EVENT_COLORS.default = "#0000ff" #optional step, set default color for events

...
:url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.event_path(id),
:color => EVENT_COLORS[self.event_type]
```