# change background color of a range of dates in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I need to change the background color of some dates. I get those dates as an array from the rails controller . lets say ["2012-12-14","2012-11-05","2012-11-16"]. I need to change the background color of these 3 dates. How do I achieve it. Please help. I am a novice in JS

Comment: Do you need to do this in Javascript? Could you not apply a CSS `background-color` value in the Rails template file?

Comment: Also, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rails way (repost i guess):

[Jquery FullCalendar- Change event color according to even_type in ruby app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790704/jquery-fullcalendar-change-event-color-according-to-even-type-in-ruby-app)

Here the JS way:

http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/08/05/building-a-shared-calendar-with-backbone-js-and-fullcalendar-a-step-by-step-tutorial/

In generel the array should contain a date and an assignd event. Based on that event you can set the colors.

The array should look like

```
[["2012-12-14","work"],["2012-11-05","work"],["2012-11-16","freetime"]]
```