# Fullcalendar - Need to set background color for specific days

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar

I am trying to set background colors for specific days. I found that this works:

`$('.fc-day15').css('backgroundColor','black');`

but the colors are on the 16th in the grid and not the day. If I knew the offset in the first week of where the 1st of the month was, I could just add the number.

EDITED:

I found this works:

```
                    var TheActualDay=15;
                    var DayOffset=($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start.getTime()-$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').visStart.getTime())/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
                    var DayNumber=(TheActualDay-1)+DayOffset;
                    $('.fc-day'+DayNumber.toString()).css('backgroundColor','black');
```

But is there a more abbreviated solution?

Comment: More explanation needed.

Comment: I made an edit above.  I did not know how to make another larger commend area like the original.

Comment: @blachawk: wrong! .fc-dayN means, that this item is Nth day on current calendar view. It don't say it's Nth day of currently showed month!  It will change according to what day of week current month starts with.

Comment: I suppose what I am looking for is something from the calendar itself that would tell me which day of the week the 1st starts on.  I am doing it with the math equation and it works, but if I am missing something in the calendar that is a simple property that tells me than that would be superior.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, thanks for clearing that up that little bit of information :)

Comment: I don't think the magic you're looking for is provided by FullCalendar. See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048658/full-calenday-cell-background-color/15052152#15052152

Answer (score 1):

This is a posible solution. Declare the viewDisplay event:

```
        viewDisplay: function(view) {
            if (view.name == 'month'){ //just in month view mode 
                var d = view.calendar.getDate(); //choise the date for cell customize
                var cell = view.dateCell(d); //get the cell location for date
                var bodyCells = view.element.find('tbody').find('td');//get all cells from current calendar
                var _element = bodyCells[cell.row*view.getColCnt() + cell.col]; //get specific cell for the date
                $(_element).css('background-color', '#FAA732'); //customize the cell
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Erik Vargas thank you for your example, i made a simple change to your code so that the first and last day would be with diferent colors.

```
viewDisplay: function(view) {  

                    if (view.name == 'month')
                    { //just in month view mode 
                        var start_date = view.start; // this is the first day of the current month ( you can see documentation in Fullcalender web page )
                        var last_date = view.end; // this is actually the 1st day of the next month ( you can see documentation in Fullcalender web page )                          
                        //var d = view.calendar.getDate(); //choise the date for cell customize                         
                        var start_cell = view.dateCell(start_date); //get the cell location for date
                        var last_cell = view.dateCell(last_date); //get the cell location for date                   
                        var bodyCells = view.element.find('tbody').find('td');//get all cells from current calendar                                                       
                        var _element_firstday = bodyCells[start_cell.row*view.getColCnt() + start_cell.col]; //get specific cell for the date
                        var _element_lastday = bodyCells[last_cell.row*view.getColCnt() + last_cell.col]; //get specific cell for the date
                        //alert(start_cell.row*view.getColCnt() + start_cell.col);

                        $(_element_firstday).css('background-color', 'black'); //customize the cell #40ACC8
                        $(_element_lastday).css('background-color', 'blue'); //customize the cell #40ACC8
                    }                   

        },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {          
        // like that
        var dateString = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        view.element.find('.fc-day[data-date="' + dateString + '"]').css('background-color', '#FAA732');

        // or that
        var cell = view.dateToCell(event.start);
        view.element.find('tr:eq(' + (cell.row + 1) + ') td:eq(' + cell.col + ')').css('background-color', '#FAA732');
    }
```

Is there better solution?